# Cauchy problem for a class of ODEs

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

[image]

It's asked also to prove that limits at zero and at $\infty$ exists, and that the limit at zero is finite, while the one at $\infty$ is $-\infty$. I don't know where to start, especially for the last two points! Thanks in advance for any answer!

Comment: Might want to translate this to English to get a larger audience

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: To make clear what the exercise is about:

"Let $h:(0,\infty)\to\mathbb{R}$ be a continuous, bounded, strictly decreasing function with $h(1) = 0$. Let $g:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ a positive, $C^1$ function with bounded derivative $g'$. Consider the solution to the Cauchy Problem $\{...$ .

Show that a) the solution $x(t)$ is defined for all $t\in (0,\infty)$"

What you first have to show is that you can solve a backward in time equation for $\tilde{x}(t) := x(1-t)$. Set $\tilde{h}(t) = h(1-t)$ such that $\tilde{x}$ satisfies

$$\tilde{x}'(t) = - x'(1-t) = -h(1-t)g(x(1-t)) = -\tilde{h}(t)g(\tilde{x}(t)).$$

with $\tilde{x}(0) = 2$. Then existence and uniqueness of a solution for $\tilde{x}$ on $[0,1)$, by restriction given by $h:(0,\infty)\to \mathbb{R}$ and also the solution $x$ of the original equation on $[1,\infty)$ follows from Picard-Lindelöf Theorem due to $g'$ being bounded. Then you glue both together to find exitence and uniqueness on all of $(0,\infty)$.

Lets go on with the limit at $\infty$. Since $h$ is strictly decreasing, it is strictly negative for $t>1$. By positivity of $g$, the derivative $x'$ is also strictly negative for $t>1$ and, therefore, $x$ strictly decreasing. If $x$ is bounded, it hence converges. Otherwise $x$ tends to $-\infty$. Assuming that $x$ is bounded and therefore converges to say $x_0$ leads to a contradiction, since $x'$ has to converge to $0$ in that case (separation of variables) but

$$0=\lim_{t\to\infty} x'(t) = \lim_{t\to\infty} h(t) g(x_0) < 0.$$

Can you go on to do the case for $x\to 0$? Everything is bounded and $g$ continuous, so you just need to combine these arguments.